# How to set cell background and decimal format together during cell selection

Tags: java, swing, matlab, awt

I am sorry if the title is not explanatory enough.

I have written a small extension to DefaultTableRenderer class in Java in order to specify cellBackgourd, cellForeground, Alignment and decimal control. I using this class in matlab to control and customise JIDE tables. But have re-created the issue in Java, in order to increase chances of a reply or a possible workaround.

I am successfully able to set cell Background, Foreground, alignment and decimal places as required when the table initialises and displays. However, as soon as I select a row/cell I loose decimal control on displayed data as shown in figure below. Please note that I am using specific cell selection colours, I guess, I am not implementing it properly.

[image]

I think, the problem is one of last two lines:

```
return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
```

or

```
return cell;
```

Java code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class DecimalPlacesInTable extends JFrame {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        DecimalPlacesInTable frame = new DecimalPlacesInTable();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public DecimalPlacesInTable() {
        Object[] columnNames = { "A", "B", "C" };
        Object[][] data = {
                {new Double( 850.503 ), new Double( 850.545 ), new Double( 80.54553 ) },
                {new Double( 50.52503 ), new Double( 36.4554 ), new Double( 50.41453 ) },
                {new Double( 80.544653 ), new Double( 8.3 ), new Double( 80.4553 ) },
                {new Double( 50.1553 ), new Double( 246.0943 ), new Double( 50.455 ) }};

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

        // Tell the table what to use to render our column of doubles
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new DecimalFormatRenderer());
            getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }
    }

    // Custom Renderer class
    static class DecimalFormatRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
    {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
                (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JComponent cell = (JComponent) super.getTableCellRendererComponent
                    (table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            // set color
            cell.setBackground(new Color(0xC8C8C8));
            cell.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));

            //set Alignment
            ((JLabel) cell).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

            //set selection colors
            if (isSelected) {
                cell.setBackground(new Color(0x3399FF));
                cell.setForeground(new Color(0x000000)); // AM
            } else {
                // set decimals
                DecimalFormat DecimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
                value = DecimalFormatter.format(value);
                return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- From [Concepts: Editors and Renderers - How to Use Tables (The Java? Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Swing Components)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

  > It is easy to customize the text or image rendered by the default renderer, `DefaultTableCellRenderer`. You just create a subclass and implement the `setValue` method so that it invokes `setText` or `setIcon` with the appropriate string or image. For example, here is how the default date renderer is implemented:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class DecimalPlacesInTable2 extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      DecimalPlacesInTable2 frame = new DecimalPlacesInTable2();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }

  public DecimalPlacesInTable2() {
    Object[] columnNames = { "A", "B", "C" };
    Object[][] data = {
      {850.503,   850.545,  80.54553},
      {50.52503,  36.4554,  50.41453},
      {80.544653, 8.3,      80.4553},
      {50.1553,   246.0943, 50.455}
    };
    //JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
      @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        return Double.class;
      }
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(model);

    // Tell the table what to use to render our column of doubles
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new DecimalFormatRenderer());
      //getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
  }

  // Custom Renderer class
  static class DecimalFormatRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private final DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
      JLabel cell = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
          table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

      //set Alignment
      cell.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

      //set selection colors
      if (isSelected) {
        cell.setBackground(new Color(0x3399FF));
        cell.setForeground(new Color(0x000000)); // AM
      } else {
        // set color
        cell.setBackground(new Color(0xC8C8C8));
        cell.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
      }

//       // set decimals
//       if (value instanceof Double) {
//         cell.setText(formatter.format(value));
//       }

      return cell;
    }
    @Override public void setValue(Object value) {
        setText(value instanceof Double ? formatter.format(value) : "");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aterai. It is pretty clear the mistake I have been making.